# skip_before_action does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to skip a before action defined in `ApplicationController` in other controller, but `skip_before_action` does not work :(

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

include Pundit
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

before_action :authenticate_usuario!
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
before_action :set_default_host_mailer
...


class Api::V1::AuthController < ApplicationController

include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
skip_before_action :authenticate_usuario!
...
```

and this is the server answer

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 25ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried with _skip_before_filter_ ?

Comment: what does your `authenticate_usuario!` method do?

Comment: Do you provide a valid token for `DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken`?

Comment: @SebastiánMeza `skip_before_filter` and the rest of the `_filter` methods are just aliases.

Comment: This error might come from `Pundit`. Comment `include Pundit` and try again

Comment: @SebastiánMeza yes, but it did not work

Comment: yes @spickermann

Comment: @OthmaneElKesri no, it didn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure the error is occurring in `Api::V1::AuthController`? Your brief log output does not give us much to go on

Comment: comment out `before_action :authenticate_usuario!` and try again because it could be that you're getting the error from elsewhere